# Garbage collector and performance hit in java

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, garbage-collection

When i was testing application deployed in tomcat, the application was hanged. Side by side i was running visualvm. During application hang time what i saw in visualvm the garbage collection was going on. I have read in theory that when garbage collection starts working the system is halt  as application threads stops during that period of time. I want to get clear idea on

**How do other developer handle this situation?**

**How it can be handled in effective way without hitting the performance of the system?**

**Can it be considered as builtin inherent property Or there can be other effective solution?**.

As, JVM can be configure with different garbage collector algorithm but in some instance of time it must run. If i am wrong in my understanding please correct me.

Comment: That is not true. The garbage collector functions *while* the program is running in the JVM to reclaim objects to which references no longer exists. If your application is hanging while it is running then I suspect there is a resource availability issue on the machine.

Comment: Depends, in most cases though if the GC is seriously interfering with performance, your code is much more likely to be the problem, than the GC. So the first thing I'd look at is what the GC was doing and why. That's a huge topic, start reading up on how the GC you have works. Often it's just poor lifetime management, ie keeping a refernce to somethng you don't need anymore.

Comment: The garbage collector is running on a different thread (as are all applications on the machine). If you have a single processor machine, then the processor switches contexts between the threads (and those of other processes which are running) which can lead to a slowdown, but this is a function of CPU speed, availability, and memory. You can make the GC lower priority, but that will just lead to a buildup in garbage memory and further degrade performance.

Answer (score 4):

Your application is hanging because GC is taking too long. I advise you to take an application performance profiling and try to understand why your application needs the GC to run so long. Look for unnecessary allocations, unused objects, collections that outgrow without any control.

I have run into this problem sometimes. The solution always involved some kind of optimization based on application performance profiling (I have used New Relic and AppDynamics for it in different occasions).

Comment: +1.  I would add "unnecessary allocations" to the list of things to look for

Comment: you are right. Unnecessary allocations are one of the main causes of these GC hang problems

Answer (score 3):

To answer your main question first: No, you don't have to accept that your application hangs. You can actually do something about it. However, there are many ways to fine tune the garbage collector, both by adjusting your code and using JVM switches that directly control the GC strategy. However, this is a wide topic that doesn't have a single best answer. It really depends on your application and your environment. The best thing you can do is to educate yourself, about it:

1.) Get an overview here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

2.) Read about specific tuning scenarios:

- http://www.jaspersoft.com/sunopenjdk-jvm-garbage-collection-tuning-tutorial
- http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=63241

3.) Read other SO questions on the same topic.

Here are some rules I use in my own code:

- I do *never* try to improve the GC behavior by invoking `System.gc()` manually "at a good time". If seen this in conjunction with stuff like [`GarbageCollectorMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getGarbageCollectorMXBeans%28%29) and [`MemoryMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryMXBean%28%29) to outsmart the garbage collector.
- When I have identified a performance problem that is reproducibly the responsibility of the GC (which is normally not the case - there are almost always other things to tune first), I look into the use of subclasses of [`Reference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) which help me distributing the load between different GC runs, for example I would check if using a [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) instead of another `Map` helps.
- I do only resort to JVM tuning as a last resort. It is often hard to document why and how parameters like  `-XX:MaxNewSize` or [`-XnoClassGC`](http://www.flester.com/blog/2008/03/24/javas-xnoclassgc-considered-harmful) should be used, and I really don't want people further down the supply chain to start experimenting with GC tuning themselves, without my understanding of the root cause of the problem.
- When I *really* see no other option, I try using `-Xms` and `-Xmx` first - *reducing* the heap size can sometimes improve garbage collection performance, and this is easy to explain, too. Setting the start heap size to the max heap size ensures that there are no pauses caused by new memory allocation - followed probably by rearranging the heap contents. Other settings that I used with good results are [`-XX:+UseParNewGC`](http://themindstorms.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/advanced-jvm-tuning-for-low-pause/) and `-XX:+UseTLAB`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to approach this:

- You can tune the JVM's garbage collection subsystem by selecting a "low pause" collector, and/or changing various tuning options.  Unfortunately low-pause collection has a cost.  You reduce the length of time that the system is paused while the GC runs, but the flip-side is that more CPU cycles are expended *overall* on the garbage collection and related things.
- You can tune your application to reduce the amount of (long lived) garbage that it creates, and how much memory it leaks.  However you need to be careful here too ... because some of the classic strategies (object pools, weak/soft reference based caches) can actually make things worse.  At the very least you should profile first before attempting to reduce allocations.

There are other possible explanations too:

- The "hangs" could be unrelated.  They could be due to talking to slow external resources.  They could be an unfortunate side-effect of threading bottlenecks.
- The "hangs" could be cause by the system as a whole "thrashing".  This happens when you try to use a heap that won't all fit into physical memory.  The system then has to swap virtual memory pages between physical memory and disc ... on demand.  Garbage collection (especially "full" GC) is likely to trigger this.